# MavenLocal unable to find repo using Gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I performed `mvn clean install` on a Java project which I wish to use as part of my Android project.

If I was using `maven`, I would do:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.abc.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-work-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

But since I'm using gradle, I tried doing:

```
compile group: 'com.abc.project', name: 'my-work-sdk', version: '2.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

But I get:

```
Error: Failed to resolve: com.abc.project:my-work-sdk:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I have added `mavenLocal()` as a repository to the root-level `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you got the my-work-sdk in a repository? And have you got that repository referenced in your build.gradle?

Comment: Hiya. The my-work-sdk is a repository that's sat locally on my machine. It's a Git repo. I'm trying to import/use it within my Android project but can't seem to get it via a Gradle compile statement.

Comment: Is it another gradle project? Have you installed it locally?

Comment: The SDK is a local Maven project. I'm trying to install it in my local Android project but through Gradle...

Comment: Is your gradle project a multi project build? As in, do you have a root project build.gradle, and then subproject build.gradles?

Answer (score 2):

**You have to explicitly set Maven local as Gradle repository**:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
```

If it is used in buildscript:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added this to the `build.gradle` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Where is the library used? Is it used in buildscript?

Comment: I have added `mavenLocal()` to the root level Gradle file inside `buildscript`.

Comment: You only need to add it to `buildscript` if it is needed for the build.gradle file to run. Otherwise, just add it at the root level of the file.

Answer (score 2):

These are the steps I think you need to take from your comments:

1. `mvn install` your `my-work-sdk` project.
2. In your gradle build.gradle project, add the mavenLocal repository:

   ```
   repositories {
       mavenLocal()
   }
   ```

If this is a multi project build, and you want the mavenLocal() repository to be accessible by all subprojects, as well as the root project, it should go under `allProjects` like so:

```
allProjects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you only want the `mavenLocal` repo to be accessible from the subprojects, you can replace `allProjects` with `subprojects`.
This should be all you need to do.

Comment: I have already added `mavenLocal()`  to the root-level `build.gradle` file.

Comment: So is your sdk actually in the local maven repo? (On windows, this can be found under `C:\Users\{userName}\.m2` by default, and `~/.m2` on a mac)

Comment: Where would it typically be on Mac?

Comment: I've managed to find it: `/Users/my.name/.m2/repository/com/...` It does live inside there. So...? Any ideas why it's not picking it up?

Comment: I've commented on  your original question. Is this project a multi-project build? Do you have sub projects with their own build.gradle files?

Comment: @Subby, I have updated the answer to show what you should do if this is a multi-project build.

Comment: Hi. It's not a multi-project build. There's just one project.

Comment: Can you add your whole build.gradle please?

Comment: Your allProjects tip really saved me, I could not make gradle search the local maven repo without it, in my multi project build, thank you